# How to write Pytest to check whether the folder structure generated from a command line interpreter is as expected?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, pytest, directory-structure

I have developed a cli that will create a set of folders up on running a command. Now I need to write tests to make sure that everything is created in place and it haven't missed any files. How can I do that using Pytest. Is there any way I can do this if I pass the folder name and its path to the test file so that pytest can check everything inside the folder.

For example, Suppose that the folder structure generated after using the cli command is as shown below,

```
.
├── app.py
├── __init__.py
├── views
│   ├── getIndex.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

How can I write tests to make sure that all the files that I have expected are already present in the structure!

Comment: This is surely possible, but the details may depend on your tool behaviour. Rough sketch: use [`tmp_path`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) fixture in test to get a path to a temp directory, feed it to your tool, afterwards use `pathlib` methods to verify all files are present (e.g. `tmp_path.rglob('*.html')` will get you all HTML files under `tmp_path` etc).

Comment: Thanks I will try that out!.Currently I am  using path_exists(dirname) to check whether directory exists

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by comparing the files in template folder with the generated folder structure. Using **os.walk(path)** we can list all files under the folders as well as sub-folders and make a comparison between them directly.